# Can't track down bug

Tags: php, curl

The following is part of a script which is used to authenticate paypal payments.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . $server . '/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

On some rare occasions there is a problem with curl_exec which causes the the script to stop executing at that line.

No errors are recorded in the cpanel error log and after trying a number of different things I am no clearer as to what may be causing this error with curl.

I am not very familiar with curl, so if anyone knows of a good way to obtain error information from this, or what could possibly cause this problem, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with a different server, or not using HTTPS?

Comment: Can you please provide a title that is more specific the next time?

Comment: any error you already have ? Apache log ?

Comment: I have had a look through all the logs I have available and when it fails, it fails silently.

Comment: Kiamlaluno edited my title which is why it doesn't seem very specific. Also I have no other servers to try it on, I can't replicate the error, it happens to about 1% of the time. I am cautious about not using https due to the sensitivity of the data being transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

It could just take a long time.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
```

Set the time out to 30 **seconds**. Are you sure you waited that long?

Use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` to set the timeout in milliseconds.

Comment: In the past I have set the timeout to 0 (as well as set_time_limit(0)) but the error persists. But I assumed if it was a timeout error, it should be throwing that after the time limit is exceeded. I am seeing no errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

`curl_error()` returns a string, it doesn't do any output/logging of its own. The proper way to detect curl errors is as follows:

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if ($result === FALSE) {
    error_log("CURL failed at " . date('c'));
    error_log("CURL message: " . curl_error($curl));
}
```

Comment: The script will not process past curl_exec. I have tried something similar to what you suggested, but unfortunately i never get to see it's output.